# В чём отличия MEAN от отдельно поставленых MongoDB + Express + Angular + Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

В чём разница, в плане кодинга, если в первом случае я поставлю MEAN и начну делать веб-приложение, а во втором поставлю всё по отдельности. В чём разница?

Comment: Что значит поставлю MEAN? Это просто стек такой)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если под "поставлю MEAN" вы имеете ввиду - `mean-cli`, то если вы поставите все по отдельности (при условии, что все сделаете правильно), то получите тот же стек MEAN.

`mean-cli` избавляет вас от необходимости повторять однообразные действия каждый раз при создании нового проекта.